# angular filtering products based on selected category, where categories in Products is an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of Food Products assigned to multiple categories and a specific vendor. example:

[image: product data]

I am pre-filtering the products based on logged in vendor.
after that I want to filter the products based on categories clicked.

I am able to achieve this someway, but it is not a nice way to filter I believe.
for prefiltering I am using this code in constructor:

```
this.foodItemCollection = this.afs.collection<FoodItem>('foodItems');
    this.foodItems = this.foodItemCollection.valueChanges({ id: 'id'}).pipe(
      map(foodItems => foodItems.filter(result => result.vendorName == this.currentUserName))
    );
```

after that on clicking the categories like fastfood, seafood, chinese etc I am calling `categoryFilter()` function.
the code of this function is like this:

```
categoryFilter(foodCategory:any){
    console.log(foodCategory);
    this.foodItems = this.foodItemCollection.valueChanges({ id: 'id'}).pipe(
      map(foodItems => foodItems.filter(result => 
        (((result.categories[0]==foodCategory.categoryName) || (result.categories[1]==foodCategory.categoryName))
        && (result.vendorName==this.currentUserName))
      ))     
    )
    return this.foodItems;
   }
```

there are multiple problems with this approach.
1.This is making a duplicate request to fetch the products which are already fetched.
2.If product contains more than 2 categories, it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single function that is called on `ngOnInit` and during `valueChanges` like so

```
justFilter() {
// assuming your using reactive forms.
const { foodCategory, itemName } = this.formGroup.value;
this.foodItems = this.foodItemCollection.valueChanges({ id: 'id' }).pipe(
  map((foodItems) =>
    foodItems.filter(
      (result) =>
        result.vendorName == this.currentUserName &&
        //filter using multiple values here!
        (
         (foodCategory.categoryName
          ? result.categories.includes(foodCategory.categoryName)
          : true) && 
          (itemName ? itemName === result.itemName : true)
         )
        // && and so on, you can write as many filters as you want!
    )
  )
);
```

}

Comment: I am applying this filter on productslist.html and I am getting only categoryName on click event.

Comment: for rendering categories in productsList I am using: `this.categoryCollection = this.afs.collection<FoodCategory>('foodCategory');
    this.foodCategories = this.categoryCollection.valueChanges({ name: 'categoryName' });` and then in html *ngfor

Comment: @Dinesh Add the filters to a form so that you can fetch all the values from the same place, another way is to add ngmodel for each filter element so that you can access them all at once!

Comment: Thanks Naren. I have modified the function as per my need. working fine.